# Excel - Generate INSERT Statements and Handle Single Quote

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have the following formula in an Excel spreadsheet:

```
="INSERT INTO #dreams VALUES('"&B3&"','"&C3&"','"&D3&"','"&E3&"','"&F3&"','"&G3&"','"&H3&"','"&I3&"')"
```

Works fine, basically, unless I have data like this in, for example, in D3.

```
US INVESTMENTS' GRADE CORPORATE BOND FUND (QUALIFIED)
```

In this case, the INSERT statement looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO #dreams VALUES('2019039','550678','US INVESTMENTS' GRADE CORPORATE BOND FUND (QUALIFIED)','F','5f','Hirofumi Nakamura','ACBD1','N')
```

That single quote will be interpreted as a delimeter. I need to have US INVESTEMENTS''

That is, substitute two single quotes for the one single quote.

I have tried various things, but can't get it to work.

EDIT: Would something similar to this work?

```
="INSERT INTO #dreams VALUES('"&B3&"','"&C3&"',=SUBSTITUTE(D2,"'","''"),'"&E3&"','"&F3&"','"&G3&"','"&H3&"','"&I3&"')"
```

Comment: What Larnu provided ... OR ... if this is a one-time event, highlight your data and perform a global search & replace ' with ''

Answer (score 3):

Wrap each of the column references with `SUBSTITUTE` and replace `'` with `''`. For example  `SUBSTITUTE(B3,"'","''")`.

Comment: Like this: ="INSERT INTO #dreams VALUES('"&B3&"','"&C3&"',SUBSTITUTE(D3,"'","''",'"&E3&"','"&F3&"','"&G3&"','"&H3&"','"&I3&"')" -- I get an error when I do this (There is a problem with this formula...)

Comment: You don't close the `SUBSTITUTE` function, @Scott . And it would be every column that might contain a `'` character.

Comment: I just closed it, same error. But yes, I will do same for other columns where appropriate.

Comment: For D3, you'd use: `="INSERT INTO #dreams VALUES('"&B3&"','"&C3&"','"&SUBSTITUTE(D3,"'","''")&"','"&E3&"','"&F3&"','"&G3&"','"&H3&"','"&I3&"')"`

Answer (score 0):

Using what @Rory said, this works:

```
="INSERT INTO #dreams VALUES('"&B3&"','"&C3&"','"&SUBSTITUTE(D3,"'","''")&"','"&E3&"','"&F3&"','"&G3&"','"&H3&"','"&I3&"')"
```